# MySQL - Replacing a subquery with something more efficient?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to work out how many orders each customer has placed and also the date of their last order. My current query is:

```
select customerID, count(*) as totalOrders, (
    select orderDate 
    from orders 
    where customerID=o.customerID 
    order by orderDate desc 
    limit 1
) lastOrder 
from orders o
group by customerID
```

This works but I am unsure whether the subquery is the most efficient way to run the query.

Is there a better way?

Comment: generally sub-queries are done for efficiency... sure beats the socks off of doing 2 queries. maybe your question is more along the lines of "is this sub-query here as efficient as it could be?"

Comment: @SnakeDoc I have always thought that subqueries were to be avoided. Maybe I am wrong and they're perfectly good. If this is the case then I'll happily stick with it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that a "Subquery" can resolve could be also done with a "JOIN", but it depends on the particular case that could be more efficient or not.

In your particular case you do not need to do a subquery because you can directly get the last date for the grouped customer with the `MAX` function.

```
SELECT customerID, COUNT(*) AS totalOrders, MAX(orderDate) AS lastOrder 
FROM orders 
GROUP BY customerID
```

Comment: This is very clever, I hadn't considered this. The simple answers are the best!

Comment: Thanks! At first I thought you query was totally fine (and it is!) but then I realise that you do not need the subquery in this case.